# 2D Binary Tree in SML

Tags: 2d, binary-tree, sml, smlnj

I am having a difficult time figuring out how to implement a 2d binary tree using sml

This is what I have so far but I get a tycon mismatch.

```
datatype btree =
                 Empty |
                 Node of int * btree * btree;


fun AddNode (i:int, Empty) = Node(i, Empty, Empty) | 
    AddNode(i:int, Node(j, left, right)) = 
        if i = j then Node(i, left, right) 
        else if i < j then Node(j, AddNode(i, left), right)
        else Node(j, left, AddNode(i, right)); 

fun printInorder Empty = () | 
    printInorder (Node(i,left,right)) =
            (printInorder left; print(Int.toString i ^ " "); printInorder right);

datatype twotree =
                Empty |
                Node of int * twotree * twotree * btree;

fun Add2Node(int:i, int:j, Empty) = Node(i, btree, Empty, Empty) |
    Add2Node(int:i, int:j, Node(k, btree, left, right)) =
        if i = k then Node(i, Addnode(j, root), left, right)
        else if i < k then Node(k, root, Add2Node(i, j, left), right)
        else Node(k, root, left, Add2Node(i, j, right));

val x : btree = AddNode(50, Empty);
val x : btree = AddNode(75, x);
val x : btree = AddNode(25, x);

printInorder(x);
```

The val were originally to test the first part of the binary tree but once I tried to do the 2d part, It created an error with the original AddNode

Comment: Did you know that `Empty` is already the name of an exception in the `List` Structure? http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.Empty:EXN Also, why does your `AddNode` Only take `btree`'s that are `Empty` rather than any `btree`?

Comment: I am kinda new at SML, I could easily program it in c++ or java. I am just having trouble transitioning from OOP to functional programming @benrudgers

Comment: Where did you define `Empty`? Where is `node` defined? What error are you getting? What is the minimum code required to reproduce it?

Comment: Things that jump out: `btree` is not a value, it's a type. The name `root` appears magically out of nowhere. Also, I would avoid reusing names of type constructors. It gets very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, You could probably just use the `btree` datatype to implement the 2d-binary tree. There is no need to define `twotree`. 
You would only have to implement the `Add2Node` function that inserts a 2d point into your `btree` by comparing the y coordinate or the x coordinate in mutual recursive calls:

```
fun Add2Node (y, x, tree) = insertY (y, x, tree)

and insertY (y, x, Empty) = Node (y, insertX (y, x, Empty), Empty) 
  | insertY (y, x, Node (k, left, right)) = 
    if y < k then 
      Node (k, insertX (y, x, left), right)
    else
      Node (k, left, insertX (y, x, right))

and insertX (y, x, Empty) = Node (x, Empty, Empty) 
  | insertX (y, x, Node (k, left, right)) =
    if x < k then
      Node (k, insertY (y, x, left), right)
    else
      Node (k, left, insertY (y, x, right))
```

The given code compiles but it is not tested. Your code for `Add2Node` does not compile according to some typos (for instance: type annotations have to be placed behind the variable and not before it like in C++ and Java). Furthermore you are using the `btree` datatype in a pattern matching position. To make it compile you would have to use one of the datatype's constructors `Empty` or `Node` here.